# Screw Modifier Best Practices

Tags: performance, screw-modifier

[image]I am creating a three-strand rope in blender using the screw modifier and was wondering what might be best practices for making a long rope. Essentially it is a choice between iterations or degrees. I typically set my degrees to 360, and then add a bunch of iterations to it, but I am not sure what uses the most memory.

Comment: Hello :). Both rotation and iterations only add *vertices*. Vertices is what uses memory, not the modifier itself. You can check the number of vertices/faces in the status bar, and see which settings result in less amount of geometry.

Comment: There is a rope maker addon and you can use Beziers with 3 circles as bevel object and twist. All should be less heavy in viewport and easier to bend.

Comment: Thank you both for the explaination on that.  Modeling ropes around branches.